# Micronaut only work with one database even connected with two databases

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, micronaut, micronaut-data

I have configured a *Micronaut* application with two *MySQL* databases but  it always performs operations with default datasource.

How can I work with multiple databases?

Here is my *application.yml* configuration:

```
datasources:
  default:
      url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/micronaut_demo
      username: root
      password: goti@181994
      dialect: MYSQL
  target:
      url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/micronaut_demo_target
      username: root
      password: goti@181994
      dialect: MYSQL
jpa:
  default:
    packages-to-scan:
      - 'com.example'
    properties:
      hibernate:
        hbm2ddl:
          auto: create-drop
        show_sql: true
  target:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        hbm2ddl:
          auto: create-drop
        show_sql: true
```

And here is my `Repository` declaration:

```
@Singleton
@Repository("target")
public class DepartmentRepositoryImpl implements  DepartmentRepository {
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public DepartmentRepositoryImpl(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    @Override
    @ReadOnly
    public Optional<Department> findById(Long id) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(entityManager.find(Department.class, id));
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Department save(String name) {
        //save logic
    }
}
```

As you can see, I specified the datasource to use with:

```
@Repository("target")
```

Comment: Could you please add the `DepartmentRepository ` declaration? And how are you calling the `DepartmentRepositoryImpl` repository bean? Could you add the caller snippet?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, 
DepartmentRepository is just interface, with only declared methods.
i am calling these methods as normal as we do, by injecting DepartmentRepository.

Answer (score 0):

You can annotate your `@Repository` beans with `@EachBean` annotation specifying `EntityManager` as the dependent type allowing for *Microanut* to create a bean per each created `EntityManager` (and each `DataSource` under the hood):

```
@EachBean(EntityManager.class)
@Repository
public class DepartmentRepositoryImpl implements  DepartmentRepository {

    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public DepartmentRepositoryImpl(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    @Override
    @ReadOnly
    public Optional<Department> findById(Long id) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(entityManager.find(Department.class, id));
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Department save(String name) {
        //save logic
    }
}
```

You can then inject a qualified `DepartmentRepository` based on the needed target `DataSource`:

```
@Singleton
public class ServiceImpl implements Service {

    private DepartmentRepository departmentRepository;

    public ServiceImpl(@Named("target") DepartmentRepository departmentRepository) {
        this.departmentRepository = departmentRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public Department save(String name) {
        return this.departmentRepository.save(name);
    }
}
```

Or dynamically using an injected `ApplicationContext`:

```
@Singleton
public class ServiceImpl implements Service {

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public ServiceImpl(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Override
    public Department save(String name) {
        return this.save(name, "default");
    }

    public Department save(String name, String targetDataSource) {
        return this.applicationContext.getBean(DepartmentRepository.class, Qualifiers.byName(target)).save(name);
    }
}
```